# how to get a open order or filled order's orderId with IB API?

Tags: c#, tws

I generated my trade system with IB API and C#.

I'm wondering whether is there a function to get the open/filled orders' orderId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IBApi.EClient.reqOpenOrders method allows to obtain all active orders submitted by the client application

```
 client.reqOpenOrders();
```

or

```
  client.reqAllOpenOrders();
```

results will be received in EWrapper with orderId and permId

```
void openOrder(int orderId, Contract contract, Order order, OrderState orderState);
```

in the end of execution you will hit `void openOrderEnd();` method in your wrapper

documentation:
https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/open_orders.html

Comment: how to let my UI thread know the result with callback, delegate or event?